# Parse feed items into nodes, but also get full html from link by scraping the site

Tags: 7, feeds

I am using feeds to create nodes from an rss feed. I also use [feeds imagegrabber](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_imagegrabber) to grab the image from the webpage.
But I can't seem to follow the links to each item and scrape it.

The feeds usually only show the teaser text, but I want to scrape the page with the full text and save it.

Can anyone explain to me how this is done?

Here is an example feed:  http://feeds.washingtonpost.com/rss/homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible at the moment, so I used Yahoo Pipes to create a new rss feed based on the original scraped the full page for each rss item and sustituted the description with the content of the full article.